# prerender content without node using vue cdn

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to vue using cdn in my existing codeigniter project. everything working on browser view like content are being fetched and populated in v-if tag, as i wanted, but when i check source of the page, i don't see fetched content there but i see the raw vue tags as i have listed below.

I guess this is bad for seo, because crawlers won't see any content in my page but it will see the vue tags like {{blog.title}} etc.

is there any possiblities to show content in source of the page rather than these in the way i am doing.

here is what i have till now.

```
    <div id="blogapp">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-col-gap" data-gutter="10">
    
          <div v-for="blog in blogs" class="col-md-3 ">
            <div class="theme-blog-item _br-4 theme-blog-item-full">
              <a class="theme-blog-item-link" href=""></a>
              <div class="banner">
                <div class="banner-bg" v-bind:style="`background-image:url('${blog.thumbnail}');`"></div>
                <div class="banner-caption banner-caption-bottom banner-caption-grad">
                  <p class="theme-blog-item-time">{{ blog.day }}</p>
                  <h5 class="theme-blog-item-title">{{ blog.title }}</h5>
                  <p class="theme-blog-item-desc">{{ blog.description.substring(0,65)+"...." }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

this is the script part

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            new Vue({
                el: '#blogapp',
                data () {
                    return {
                       blogs: [],
                    }
                },
                methods: {
                    getBlogs () {
                    axios
                    .get('https://www.happyvoyaging.com/api/blog/list?appkey="grv250531"',{
                        params: {
                        limit: 4
                        }
                    })
                    .then(res => (this.blogs = res.data.response.posts))
                    .catch(error => console.log(error))
                },
                },
                mounted() {
                   this.getBlogs();
                 },
                })
        </script>
```

Comment: Yes, it's called server-side rendering. https://ssr.vuejs.org/

Comment: but i think, it is not possible to do while i am working with cdn version only.